# email authentication failure using python on godaddy shared host

Tags: python

I have a python program that has been running well for several years on a laptop in my office. The laptop is a windows device and python was installed using a windows installer. I am using python 2.7.8 on my laptop. The program basically checks an email address for specific emails and if it finds them it processes the data in them, re-packages the data into png's and ftp's it to a specific folder on my Godaddy shared hosting account and my website will then display the images. Been working fine for years. However that laptop has now died and it's now time I put this python program in the cloud. While Godaddy does has python its default version is 2.6.6 but you can access their 2.7.2 version with #!/usr/local/bin/python2.7 but since it is only 2.7.2 I decided to install python 2.7.8 on my shared hosting account since that is the version I have been successful with. So now that I have manually installed python I am running my program via SSH to see where it chokes and add the necessary packages. I am at a point where I am a bit stumped. I am getting a connection refused error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CTWRT.py", line 627, in <module>
    myEmailConnection = poplib.POP3_SSL(mailServer)
  File "/home/tcimaglia/python27/lib/python2.7/poplib.py", line 350, in __init__
    raise socket.error, msg
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

mailServer = "pop.secureserver.net"

Does this have anything to do with running this program on the Godaddy shared host and trying to access an email that is linked to this account, something@my-domain.com?  This command works just fine when running on my laptop. Should mailServer be something else?

Comment: as a guess, this is something with Your network maybe because, I tested given snippet and Python connects and returns instance for me`<poplib.POP3_SSL instance at 0x7fce38e8ac68>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Take_Care. I know the code works when I am running it on a laptop connected to my office network. My problem is that I ported it to my Ultimate Linux cPanel hosting account on Godaddy and I have SSH'd into the hosting account and am now trying to run it. So because I am logged into the account which also hosts the email account I am trying to access is this a problem?